# How can I always force the customized Power App list forms to show inside mobile app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, mobile

I have a custom list where I customized its list forms using power app, now if I use the mobile app >> I go directly to the list >> click on new >> I will not get the power app forms, rather I will get a form which show all the fields..

While if I copy the URL of the list forms from my PC as follow:-

[image]

then I added a modern page >> and I added button with the above URL, as follow:-

[image]

then inside mobile devices if I click on the button I will get power app forms..

so my question is if I can force the power apps forms to always show inside the mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

Custom List forms via Power Apps are not supported (today) in the SharePoint mobile app List view but as you noted, renders in the embedded browser view.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, but why when i click on the button which contain the form url,, the power app will be shown?

Comment: As mentioned in Trevor's answer, it renders in the embedded browser view rather than part of the app's native functionality.